Joint Probability Function of Independent Binomial Random Variables
I am brushing up on some probability theory using Practical Nonparametric Statistics 2nd Edition by Conover and have been reviewing random variables. There was one problem that stuck out to me and I'm not sure where I went wrong:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent, binomially distributed random variables, with parameters $n=3$, $p=\frac{1}{2}$ for $X$, and $n=4$, $p=\frac{1}{2}$ for $Y$. Let $f(x,y)$ denote the joint probability function of $X$ and $Y$. Find $f(3,4)$.
Here is my approach. Since these random variables are independent, we can say the following:
$f(3,4)=P(X=3,Y=4)=P(X=3)P(Y=4)$
Since both variables are binomially distributed, we can also say:
$P(X=3)=\binom{3}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^{3}(1-\frac{1}{2})^{3-3}=\frac{1}{8}$
$P(Y=4)=\binom{4}{4}(\frac{1}{2})^{4}(1-\frac{1}{2})^{4-4}=\frac{1}{16}$
Therefore, we have $P(X=3)P(Y=4)=\frac{1}{8}*\frac{1}{16}=\frac{1}{128}$. However, my book says the answer is $\frac{4}{128}$. The only way I could see this is if we used $\binom{4}{3}$ for $P(X=3)$, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Which book and what question?

Practical Nonparametric Statistics 2nd Edition by W.J. Conover. This question is from chapter 1.3, question 3, part d.

The Third edition (1999) gives the questions and answers for 3(b) as $f(0,1)=\frac{4}{128}$ and 3(d) as $f(3,4)= \frac{1}{128}$ which both look correct.  I cannot check the Second edition (1980).

Interesting. For the second edition, 3(b) gives $f(0,1)=\frac{4}{128}$ and 3(d) gives $f(3,4)=\frac{4}{128}$ as well.

If that is the question, and that is the given answer, then the book is in error and your work is correct.
Since $X,Y$ are independent binomial distributions, with  $X\sim\mathcal{Bin}(3,1/2), Y\sim\mathcal{Bin}(4,1/2)$, therefore:
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{\;=\;}3,Y{\;=\;}4) &= \binom 33 \left(\frac 12\right)^3\left(\frac 12\right)^0\cdot\binom44\left(\frac 12\right)^4\left(\frac 12\right)^0 \\[1ex]&= \frac 1{128}&\color{green}\checkmark\end{align}$

Moreover, the answer given is not even right for independent binomial distributions, with $X\sim\mathcal{Bin}(4,1/2), Y\sim\mathcal{Bin}(4,1/2)$, whence:
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{\;=\;}3,Y{\;=\;}4) &= \binom 43 \left(\frac 12\right)^3\left(\frac 12\right)^1\cdot\binom44\left(\frac 12\right)^4\left(\frac 12\right)^0 \\[1ex]&= \frac 2{128}\end{align}$

TL:DR The answer given clearly has a typographical error.
    Or you've looked up the wrong answer, missed something in the question, or ...

Thank you. I had my doubts and have repeatedly made sure I was looking at the right section, looks to be a typo.
